# PrimeNG dropdown dynamic options and preselected item on event fired not work the first time but works in the next times

Tags: binding, dropdown, primeng

If dropdown options are assigned dynamically as a response of an event, the select option is always the first one the first time that event is fired and in all next executions, the selected option is correct. If an idle time is used, the behavior is the expected.

Run the stackblitz example and click in the button to confirm that the preselection is wrong (always the first element of the list) but then, the second time (and all other times after) the correct value is bind. Another "curious" fact is that if we comment the line for assign the preselected item and uncomment the setTimeout() line (meaning doing the assignment after a very short idle time), it works as expected.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-n9ynk8

How should I do the bind avoiding the idle time?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  options: Array<number> = [];
  value: number;

  constructor() {}

  buttonOnClick() {
    this.options = [1, 2, 3];
    this.value = 3;
    //setTimeout(() => { this.value = 3; }, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<p-button (onClick)="buttonOnClick()">Bind Dropdown</p-button>
<br />
<p-dropdown
  id="demoDropdown"
  [options]="options"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG dropdown component have a property called: "autoDisplayFirst" activated by default that as its name suggest it auto-preselect the first option always. To solve the issue we need to disable that feature:

```html
<p-dropdown
  id="demoDropdown"
  [options]="options"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
></p-dropdown>
```